# How to send multiple get requests to a website in Python?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm in internship for 3 months in a computer science laboratory (LIRIS). My internship supervisor asks me to retrieve some data on [meilleurs-agents.com](https://www.meilleursagents.com/). This is a real estate website and I would like to retrieve the price of square meter for each city. My program is in Python and I actually try to send multiple requests to get data. But it doesn't work because of a proxy error :

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='XXXXXX', port=XXXX): Max retries exceeded with url: "..." (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000000B304320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))
```

A preview of my code :

```
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
})  
for city, postal_code in zip(cities, postal_codes):
    url = 'https://www.meilleursagents.com/prix-immobilier/'+city+'-'+postal_code+'/'

    PROXY = {'https' : 'XX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX'}

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10, proxies=PROXY)
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
```

If I remove the proxy, my request works but the html code contains a message like "you seems to be a bot so your request hasn't been completed" so I can't get prices... But I really need this data

Hope that my problem is clear and that someone could help me :)

Thanks, Nelly

PS : Sorry for my English, I'm a French student :D

Comment: Perhaps you can try another User Agent?

Comment: Is there an English version to this website by any chance lol? It's coming up in French in my browser.

Comment: Always hide IP addresses in your questions. You may be exposing a vulnerable server.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer :D I have tried multiple user-agent and nothing changed... I think that the website blocked my multiple requests, I must wait about 1 hour between each query :D And no, there is no English version

Comment: @eqperes I didn't know about that, I will remember, thank for the advise :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `User-Agent` header and cookies for your requests.

Another workaround is to try adding some timeout between requests:

```
time.sleep(1)  # try to use different time values
```

This of course will slow down your script, but may help to avoid too-many-requests errors.